# Parse file and store string after match in variable for each line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have file a.txt

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

How to parse every line in this file to get values after `=`, ie, get values after

```
GOARCH=
GOBIN=
GOEXE=
GOHOSTARCH=
GOHOSTOS=
GOOS=
GOPATH=
GORACE=
GOROOT=
GOTOOLDIR=
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=
CC=
GOGCCFLAGS=
CXX=
CGO_ENABLED=
```

and store each line in separate variable

for example, for first line

```
echo $goarch
amd64
```

second line

```
echo $gobin
```

and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create variables `GOARCH`, `GOBIN`, etc, you could source the file using the dot command:

```sh
. a.txt
```

To create lowercase variables you could use GNU sed:

```sh
. <(sed 's/.*="/\L&/' a.txt)
```

The dot is a builtin command documented in [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)

Comment: thanks @sergio, i'm not by the computer right now, can you please explain more ? after i source file GOARCH, GOBIN, etc, will be automatically saved in memory ?

Comment: Long version: `source a.txt`. See `help source`.

Comment: @xerks The dot command reads and  executes commands from the file in the current shell environment. I included a link to the documentation. Or use  `help source` or `help .` as mentioned in earlier comment.